# Zeros of multiplicative wave function renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, critical-phenomena, analyticity

It is probably needless to recall here that the Reimann zeta function $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$$ and its generalizations are among the central objects of study in mathematics.

The main open problem about them is the famous Riemann hypothesis, which is the statement
$$
\left( Re(s)>0 \text{ and } \zeta(s)=0 \right) \implies Re(s)=\frac{1}{2},
$$
where $Re(s)$ denotes the real part of the complex number $s$. Note that the definition of $\zeta$ that I wrote does not make sense for $Re(s) \leq 1$ because the sum is not convergent. But it is possible to define $\zeta$ in a more sophisticated way so that the definition makes sense for any complex number $s \neq 1$ (Riemann).

At the end of [this](https://doi.org/10.1515/form.2004.16.6.789) very interesting article of Burnol ([arXiv:math/0112254](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0112254)), some speculations relating the zeta function and its generalizations to ideas associated with the renormalization group are proposed.

The author suggests that the zeta function should be analogous to a multiplicative wave function renormalization and that the zeros of such a function are related to critical exponents. I am just a mathematician curious about physics and I would be very happy to understand such a statement better. I am aware that critical exponents describe the behavior of physical quantities in the neighborhood of continuous phase transitions.

Hence the following questions. What is a multiplicative wave function renormalization and what is the connection between its zeros and critical exponents?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_theory

Comment: When computing critical exponents using zeta regularization, the exponents are related to the residues of the poles of the analytically-continued functions, not the zeros.